# Is it a right choice to use AD for user meta data?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012

Currently, we are using the Active Directory of Windows 2012 Server to manage user accounts.  But now I need to store the users' status like "active" or "inactive", other than that, the user may have more than one key files.  Is it still appropriate to continue use AD/ldap to store those information?

I'm pretty new to LDAP/AD.  Looking forward to advises...

Comment: Your question is not clear. AD has a status of "active/inactive", see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781527(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: OK.  It's a customized user property.  Basically, my requirement is adding customized properties, and public keys.